# How to use select statement in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_pop1()
DECLARE
ROUTERNAME varchar2(100);
BEGIN
SELECT ROUTERNAME INTO routername FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS;
END;
```

I tried to execute this procedure. But it gives error. Please anyone tell me whats mistake I have done.

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the
 following:
 <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
 current delete exists prior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probaly a clash between the variable and the column name. The easiest solution is to rename your variable.

Also procedures with no parameters do not need the parentheses. The [correct syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/procedure.htm#LNPLS01336) would be something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_pop1
AS
    ROUTERNAME_V varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT ROUTERNAME
        INTO ROUTERNAME_V
        FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
END;
```

Comment: I have tried with different variable name, same error is giving

Comment: Hi, I have tried with above code, I am getting like:
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "NSACR.GET_POP1", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Please anyone tell me the solution

Comment: @user3165241 this is because your query returns more than one row (that is, your table has more than one row). As a variable can only contain a single information, you have to add a `WHERE` clause that will ensure only one row. Example edited to show this. You can also have array variables if you want multiple results in a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of brackets "()" and rename `DECLARE` to `IS` or `AS`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_pop1
is
  ROUTERNAME varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'blah-blah-blah' INTO routername FROM dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(routername);
END get_pop1;

begin
  get_pop1();
end;

blah-blah-blah

Statement processed.


0.00 seconds
```

Change the body of the procedure with your code. You might need to have a table variable if `ROUTERNAME` is not unique in the table `routername`. In this case, to read from the table use `BULK COLLECT INTO` instead of `INTO`.